# What kind of PCA is performed by the PCA widget

Tags: data-mining, pca, orange

I am wondering if PCA widget was performing centred and/or normalized PCA. I did'nt find any corresponding option in the widget.

Does anyone know the answer and if there is plan to add these options?

Thanks alot. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 'PCA' widget both centers and standardizes the data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, PCA is *defined* to be on standardized data.

The use of the term PCA for performing SVD on other matrixes (such as non-central correlation matrixes) is *much* less common - because there is a proper term for that, too: SVD.

Furthermore, using it on non-centered data means that the transformation is sensitive to data translation; an aspect one usually does not want.

So unless explicitly specified, you should assume that PCA is implemented by

1. Centering the data
2. Computing the covariance matrix
3. Applying SVD on the covariance matrix to decompose it as desired